# How to download a local CSV file from a vue.js webpage?

Tags: javascript, csv, vue.js, download

I'm new to vue.js and I am mainly wondering how I can have my webpage display a download link for downloading a csv file that I have stored locally.

I have created a component Template.vue. Inside it I have

```
<a :href="item.loc" download>  {{item.title}} </a>
```

And in the export I have this:

```
export default {
  name: 'Template',
  data () {
    return {
      item: {loc: require("../assets/example.csv")}
    }
  }
}
```

At the moment this doesn't work for CSV-files. I received the following error when I tried to run this code with a CSV-file:

"./src/assets/example.csv
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:14)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type."

However, if I would try to download an image(png) then it works. How do I go about implementing a loader? Or are there other ways to solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using vue-cli? If you do i guess you could do something like

```
import csvFile from "../assets/example.csv"

export default {
  name: "Template",
  data() {
    return {
      item: csvFile
    }
  }
}

// in your template

<a :href="item"> </a>
```

If your csv-file isn't dynamically generated, you could probably use it as a static asset and just link to it's path. It's been a while since i've done anything with Vue, but according to a quick glance at the docs i think you can put your csv file into your static folder and reference it like this:

```
<a href="./assets/example.csv">{{someTitle}}</a>
```

*Link to docs:*
[https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#disable-index-generation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports)

Comment: I tried your suggestions and I still have the same problem. Your method works for png files but not for csv. I get the same error that I need a loader for that filetype. Any idea on how to implement a loader?

Comment: Your first suggestion works for me. It saves my time! Thank you a lot!

Comment: @SunghoMoon Thats good to hear! Maybe they've added a default csv-loader since last time the question were asked.

Comment: @Jordan did you resolve the issue? When looking at it again i think the problem might be that you're using require which i believe is valuated at runtime, while import is valuated at "compile" time though i am not sure about it making a difference

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer :

1)-Install the loader with `npm i csv-loader -D`
2)-add this code into the `vue.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
       chainWebpack: config => {
        config
          .module
          .rule('csv')
          .test(/\.csv$/)
          .use('csv-loader')
          .loader('csv-loader')
          .options({
             dynamicTyping: true,
             header: true,
            skipEmptyLines: true
          })
           .end()
   }
}
```

3)-then you can import local files into your components,the file will automatically be converted to a js object:

```
    import csv from './assets/file.csv'
    export default{
      created(){
        console.log(csv)
    }
  }
```

and here is a link to the answer:https://www.fabiofranchino.com/log/include-csv-in-vue-cli-project/